# How to upload XML in Keycloak client registration?

Tags: keycloak

I just installed `keycloak`.

Then I do `nextcloud` integration to the `keycloak` but when I upload `metadata.xml`, I get the error message:

```
**Error! An unexpected server error has occurred**
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Please check server.log of your Keycloak.

Comment: Yes, check server logs. Usually, it is a problem with XML syntax or with keys, which are attached in the XML.

Comment: I get information from server.log

java.io.IOException : Illegal footer: ----BEGINCERTIFICATE-----

XML error syntax ??